# Managing groups in SignalR service in Azure function

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions

I have implemented negotiate endpoint and send method and connected from signalR JS client. I am getting the connection and able to broadcast message to all connected clients. As per our requirement, I have to send the message to a few clients. From the documentation, I believe we can send messages to a group. I have written an azure function for Adding and removing a user to a group.

```
 [FunctionName("AddToGroup")]
        public static Task AddToGroup(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            [SignalR(HubName = NotificationConstants.Hub)]IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction> signalRGroupActions)
        {
            string userId = req.Query[NotificationConstants.QueryStringUserId];
            string companyId = req.Query[NotificationConstants.QueryStringCompanyId];
            return signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
                 new SignalRGroupAction
                 {
                     UserId = userId,
                     GroupName = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                NotificationConstants.Group,
                                companyId),
                     Action = GroupAction.Add
                 });
        }

    [FunctionName("RemoveFromGroup")]
    public static Task removeFromGroup(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req,
       ILogger log,
       [SignalR(HubName = NotificationConstants.Hub)]IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction> signalRGroupActions)
    {
        string userId = req.Query[NotificationConstants.QueryStringUserId];
        string companyId = req.Query[NotificationConstants.QueryStringCompanyId];
        return signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
             new SignalRGroupAction
             {
                 UserId = userId,
                 GroupName = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                            NotificationConstants.Group,
                            companyId),
                 Action = GroupAction.Remove
             });
    }
```

How I can call this from JS Client? My sample client code as below. Please suggest

```
function GetConnectionInfo() {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:7071/api/ConnectionInfo?UserId=1_2347')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }).catch(console.error);
}

function StartConnection(connection) {
    console.log('connecting...');
    connection.start()
        .then(function () {
            console.log('connected!');
            connection.invoke('getConnectionId')
                .then(function (connectionId) {
                    console.log(connectionId);
                    // Send the connectionId to controller
                });

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            setTimeout(function () { StartConnection(connection); }, 2000);
        });
}

GetConnectionInfo().then(function (info) {
    let accessToken = info.accessToken;
    const options = {
        accessTokenFactory: function () {
            if (accessToken) {
                const _accessToken = accessToken;
                accessToken = null;
                return _accessToken;
            } else {
                return GetConnectionInfo().then(function (info) {
                    return info.accessToken;
                });
            }

        }
    };

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(info.url, options)
        .build();
    StartConnection(connection);

    connection.on('DocumentStatusUpdated', ProcessDocumentData);

    connection.onclose(function () {
        console.log('disconnected');
        setTimeout(function () { StartConnection(connection); }, 5000);
    });
}).catch(console.error);
```

Can someone please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you've shared, you would need the `userId` and `companyId` of the users you want add into your group and simple make `axios.get()` calls accordingly.

For sending the message to the specific group, you would need one more function. The doc has [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service#send-to-a-group) for the same. Here is the same for reference

```cs
[FunctionName("SendMessage")]
public static Task SendMessage(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]object message,
    [SignalR(HubName = "chat")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)
{
    return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
        new SignalRMessage
        {
            // the message will be sent to the group with this name
            GroupName = "myGroup",
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new [] { message }
        });
}
```

And you would make an `axios.post()` call to this endpoint to send a message to the group created earlier.